# How to split columns with 3 data attributes in-name into several columns, then collapse across different levels of aggregation?

Tags: r, split, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a large dataframe that takes the below form, where each column labels year, commodity, and unit. Each observation corresponds to a mine, and each value is amount produced.

```
library(tibble)
rdf <- tribble(
  ~`1997_Silver_oz`, ~`1998_Diamonds_ct`, ~`1999_Coal_lbs`, ~`1999_Copper_tonnes`,
    150000, 20000, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
    NA_integer_, 50000, NA_integer_, 1,
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
    40000, 205000, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
)
```

I want to collapse these data down to two levels of aggregation, to see where there's non-zero production for each Year and Commodity/Year.

What is the intermediate step I need to take to split my existing columns into multiple, like the below?

```
rdf_gathered <- tribble(
  ~year, ~commodity, ~unit, ~amount,
   1997, 'Silver', 'oz', 150000,
   1997, 'Silver', 'oz', NA_integer_,
   1997, 'Silver', 'oz', NA_integer_,
   1997, 'Silver', 'oz', 40000,
   1998, 'Diamonds', 'ct', 20000,
   1998, 'Diamonds', 'ct', 50000,
   1998, 'Diamonds', 'ct', NA_integer_,
   1998, 'Diamonds', 'ct', 205000,
   1999, 'Coal', 'lbs', NA_integer_,
   1999, 'Coal', 'lbs', NA_integer_,
   1999, 'Coal', 'lbs', NA_integer_,
   1999, 'Coal', 'lbs', NA_integer_,
   1999, 'Copper', 'tonnes', NA_integer_,
   1999, 'Copper', 'tonnes', 1,
   1999, 'Copper', 'tonnes', NA_integer_,
   1999, 'Copper', 'tonnes', NA_integer_
)
```

And after that step, what step should I take to collapse this dataframe into one that measures non-zero production, like the below? [NA -> 0, else 1]

```
# Collapse
rdf_collapsed_v1 <- tribble(
  ~`1997_Silver`, ~`1998_Diamonds`, ~`1999_Coal`, ~`1999_Copper`,
    1, 1, 0, 1
) 

rdf_collapsed_v2 <- tribble(
  ~`1997`, ~`1998`, ~`1999`,
  1, 1, 1
)
```

I use/mostly prefer tidyverse functions but interested in any elegant base solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some straightforward dplyr operations.

The only tricky bit is when I use `summarise` and `any` to create a logical test by group, then multiply `*1` to convert that logical result to binary (0 or 1). `any` is great for testing groups!

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
rdf <- tribble(
  ~`1997_Silver_oz`, ~`1998_Diamonds_ct`, ~`1999_Coal_lbs`, ~`1999_Copper_tonnes`,
    150000, 20000, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
    NA_integer_, 50000, NA_integer_, 1,
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
    40000, 205000, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
)  

# Create Tidy Data  
rdf <- rdf %>% 
    gather(key, value) %>% 
    separate(key, into= c("year", "commodity", "unit"), sep="_") %>% 
    mutate(value = replace_na(value, 0))

# A tibble: 16 x 4
   year  commodity unit    value
   <chr> <chr>     <chr>   <dbl>
 1 1997  Silver    oz     150000
 2 1997  Silver    oz          0
 3 1997  Silver    oz          0
 4 1997  Silver    oz      40000
 5 1998  Diamonds  ct      20000
 6 1998  Diamonds  ct      50000
 7 1998  Diamonds  ct          0
 8 1998  Diamonds  ct     205000
 9 1999  Coal      lbs         0
10 1999  Coal      lbs         0
11 1999  Coal      lbs         0
12 1999  Coal      lbs         0
13 1999  Copper    tonnes      0
14 1999  Copper    tonnes      1
15 1999  Copper    tonnes      0
16 1999  Copper    tonnes      0

# First Operation
rdf %>% 
  group_by(year,commodity) %>% 
  summarise(non.zero = any(value>0)*1 ) %>% 
  unite("year_commodity", c("year", "commodity"), sep = "_", remove = T) %>% 
  spread(year_commodity, non.zero)

#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   `1997_Silver` `1998_Diamonds` `1999_Coal` `1999_Copper`
#>           <dbl>           <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1             1               1           0             1

#Second Operation
rdf %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(non.zero = any(value>0)*1 ) %>% 
  spread(year, non.zero)

#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   `1997` `1998` `1999`
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1      1      1      1
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: This is great. How could I use this while keeping constant ID information specific to each attribute in the original data.frame? Say if the original data had its leftmost columns include asset names, types, and numbers?

Comment: in this case, you should be able to `gather(key, value, -asset_names, -asset_types, -asset_numbers)` and later use `group(year, asset_names, asset_types, asset_numbers)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gather` and `separate` for the first task

```
library(tidyr)
rdf_gathered <- gather(rdf, key, amount) %>% 
  separate(col = key, into = c("year", "commodity", "unit"))
rdf_gathered
# A tibble: 16 x 4
#   year  commodity unit   amount
#   <chr> <chr>     <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 1997  Silver    oz     150000
# 2 1997  Silver    oz         NA
# 3 1997  Silver    oz         NA
# 4 1997  Silver    oz      40000
# ...
```

---

And here is a `base R` approach for the second task

```
rdf_collapsed_v1 <- sapply(rdf, function(x) as.integer(!is.na(x)))
#     1997_Silver_oz 1998_Diamonds_ct 1999_Coal_lbs 1999_Copper_tonnes
#[1,]              1                1             0                  0
#[2,]              0                1             0                  1
#[3,]              0                0             0                  0
#[4,]              1                1             0                  0
```

This yields a `matrix` so wrap this in `as.data.frame` if needed.

---

For the third you might use `rdf_gathered` and `dplyr` verbs.

```
library(dplyr)
rdf_gathered %>% 
  mutate(amount = as.integer(!is.na(amount))) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(amount = sum(amount))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  year  amount
#  <chr>  <int>
#1 1997       2
#2 1998       3
#3 1999       1
```